Celery periodic task with select DB data

I set up sending birthday greetings based on the data in the database.
Using Python and Celery(on_after_configure).
It looks like this:
from flask import Flask
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery import Celery
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

today = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m")
    
    @celery.on_after_configure.connect
    def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
        emails = DB.get_email_today(today) #getting a list of birthday emails today
        for row in emails:
            email = row['email']
            first_name = row['first_name']
            last_name = row['last_name']
            sender.add_periodic_task(
                crontab(hour=12, minute=20),
                sender.send_email.s(email, first_name, last_name),
            )

The problem is that today is calculated only at the moment the application starts and is not updated every day.
Tell me how this can be configured?

You are defining the today variable in the global scope of the application, therefore it is set when you first run the application.
You could add a task, which includes getting the current date and the rest of the logic execution and then schedule it with @app.on_after_configure.connect
@app.task
def task():
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    emails = DB.get_email_today()
    ...
    *Your desired code logic*

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def schedule_task(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(crontab(hour=12, minute=20), task.s(), "Send 
    Birthday Mails")
    ....

Reference here

Thank you very much, in the end I did as you advised. Initially, I wanted to pass arguments specifically to add_periodic_task(), so that I could subsequently see them in Flower.
Of course, this solution worsens the readability of tasks in Flower, but it works)

I see, obviously you can do this as well, simply need to re-structure the task and scheduler aspect respectively for your need. The core issue with your setup was that today has been defined globally, and not within the function call. Feel free to accept the answer if it was able to solve your issue.
